# Typo in ROS Wiki Page on Building Packages

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I found the following line in the ROS Wiki tutorial for building ROS packages [http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/BuildingPackages]:

> You should see a lot of output from cmake and ***them*** make, which should be similar to this:

I think the "**them**" should be "**then**", or even totally absent. Am I right? If I so, how do I correct it or any other typo I discover later?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309872/typo-in-ros-wiki-page-on-building-packages/) by [holadepo](https://answers.ros.org/users/38807/holadepo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2018-12-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can sign up for a wiki account and edit the wiki page yourself: http://wiki.ros.org/action/newaccount/Documentation?action=newaccount

In the meantime, I've fixed the typo on that page.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [holadepo](https://answers.ros.org/users/38807/holadepo/) on 2018-12-03**:
Thanks.
After signing up and logging in, a message was displayed about having to be added to a whitelist before gaining permission to edit the wiki. To gain permission, you have to comment on [this Github ticket](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/issues/258) with your wiki username.

**Comment by [holadepo](https://answers.ros.org/users/38807/holadepo/) on 2018-12-03**:
The typo mentioned above was fixed today, but the last edit date of the page is still '2012-12-24 23:17:03'. Could that be and error?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-12-03**:
That is not an error. That page includes two other pages, one for the catkin version and one for the older rosbuild version. I only needed to update the catkin version.